# Quickest way to find all elements by an array of Ids with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

Given an array of objects like:

```
var things = [{
   "id": "123a",
   "name": "456"
},{
   "id": 123b",
   "name": 456"
},{
   "id": "123c",
   name": "456"
},{
   "id": "123d",
   "name": "456"
}];
```

What is the quickest way to find all elements that contain those ids.

Currently I'm just doing something along the lines of:

```
$.each(things, function(i, e) {
    $row = $('td[vid=' + e.id + ']', table);
});
```

But it feels slowish. This is working with a large grid of data on the client, 40 columns, 250 rows. Table is full of single values, a matrix of data, and I need to find cells and modify the value, so I could be updating an entire column of data.

Wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Edit:

So basically the table structure is along the lines of:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th vid="1">Version 1</th>
      <th vid="2">Version 2</th>
      <th vid="3">Version 3</th>
      <th vid="4">Version 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td destid="1">Dest 1</td>
      <td destid="2" vid="1">x</td>
      <td destid="2" vid="2">x</td>
      <td destid="2" vid="3">x</td>
      <td destid="2" vid="4">x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td destid="2">Dest 2</td>
      <td destid="2" vid="1">x</td>
      <td destid="2" vid="2">x</td>
      <td destid="2" vid="3">x</td>
      <td destid="2" vid="4">x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td destid="3">Dest 3</td>
      <td destid="3" vid="1">x</td>
      <td destid="3" vid="2">x</td>
      <td destid="3" vid="3">x</td>
      <td destid="3" vid="4">x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you select from the top on a version, then the result would be:

```
[{
  id: 5,
  vid: 2,
  destid: 1
},{
  id: 6,
  vid: 2,
  destid: 2
},{
  id: 7,
  vid: 2,
  destid: 3
}]
```

Likewise it would be similar when selecting a destination for all versions.

---

I think the best method for me will be to refactor the cells to be:

`id="2-1"` | `id="2-2"` | `id="2-3"`

And then use `var cell = document.getElementById(data.vid + "-" + data.destid);`

Rather than currently looking for a cell like:

`var cell = $('td[vid=' + data.vid + '][destid=' + data.destid + ']', table);`

Comment: I would generate something like this via a server sided script (PHP, ASP, etc.). As far as modification goes, why don't you just set an ID to the column so that you can access it quickly with `$('#idhere')`

Comment: If I'm looking an a vertical column, maybe its possible to look at the index instead of the id, and just find the first one and the index of all the rest.

Comment: Also, its not a getById, because theres no Id to set, theres 3 ways to identify it based on certain data. :( If the cell is currently empty, theres no data so i have to find it by row id / column id. For example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3C states that ids should be unique. Therefore, specifying anything more than the id, for selection, is typically superfluous.

```
$row = $('#' + e.id)
```

This executes much faster than the example you postulated, as it maps directly to native `document.getElementbyId()` . Also, with the example you postulated jQuery has to manually traverse the DOM, which is expensive.

### **Update:**

You later mentioned the use of composites for ids, as fields containing unique values is not guaranteed. This solution is workable, however, I would augment it to include sensible namespacing—for readability, and to prevent id clashing (ie: two tables on the same page using the same id scheme.).

**Here is the proposed solution based on the updated constraints:**

```
var vid_id = '1';
var dest_id = '1';
var dom_query = '#' + 'vid_id-' + vid_id +'dest_id' + dest_id;

$row = $(dom_query);
```

This solution can be optimized for use without jQuery if necessary.

---

**W3C specification on ids:**
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

**Decent synopsis on jQuery optimizations:**
http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/

Comment: This assumes the there is an id to begin with, which there isn't :( Maybe I can make a composite id like `id="vid-destid"`, then concat them together on a `getElementById(vid + "-" + destid)`. Just means when there is an Id for that cell I can't assign it.

Comment: @Phill Please provide further insight into the dataset referred to in the question. There wasn't any indication of "id" or "name" being null. But yes, selecting would be faster if you could provide a composite id.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I updated the question and have gone with the composite solution, its much faster, thanks for giving me the idea. Feel free to update your answer with the composite solution and I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have html like this :

```
<div>
    <p id = "123a">p1</p>
    <p id = "123c">p2</p>
    <p id = "123d">p3</p>
    <p id = "122222">p4</p>
</div>

$.map(things,function(thing,i){
   $('div p').filter(function(index){
     return $(this).attr('id') == thing.id;
   }).css('color','green');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jY2u6/